# Insert a value to a map of map when none of the map is initialized

Tags: c++, dictionary

I've seen a code that does the following behavior:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> obj;

obj["123"]["456"] = "789";
```

How does it make sense? The first map (obj["123"]) was not needed to be initialized first? such as:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> obj;
obj["123"] = std::map<std::string,std::string>();
obj["123"]["456"] = "789";
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `[]` to "index" a map, if the key isn't found then an entry will be created and inserted into the map for that key.

So for your example:

```
obj["123"]["456"] = "789";
```

that is essentially equal to

```
// Create an element for the key "123", and store a std::map<std::string, std::string> object for that key
obj.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>("123", std::map<std::string, std::string>()));

// Create an element for the key "456" in the map obj["123"]
obj["123"].insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("456", "789"));
```

Comment: great explanation. Thanks programmer dude!